# Aspect ratio (vs. size and position) of inset_axis of axes_divider host axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib, I can create square inset_axes in rectangular host axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

base_ax = plt.axes()

loc="upper left"
size = 20

bbox = base_ax.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_right_upper = inset_axes(
    base_ax, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)
```

[image]

When I add ordinary axes, I can then easily programatically create inset axes with e.g. square aspect ratios and specific locations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

base_ax = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 0), rowspan=3, colspan=3)
ax_right = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (0, 3), rowspan=3, colspan=1)
ax_bottom = plt.subplot2grid((4, 4), (3, 0), colspan=3)

loc="upper left"
size = 20

bbox = ax_right.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_right_upper = inset_axes(
    ax_right, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)

bbox = ax_bottom.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_bottom_upper = inset_axes(
    ax_bottom, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)
```

[image]

Alternatively, I can adjoin axes to an anchor axis with the axis_divider pattern, and then add insets to the adjoined axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

base_ax = plt.axes()
divider = make_axes_locatable(base_ax)
ax_right = divider.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad="1%")
ax_bottom = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="20%", pad="1%")

loc="upper left"
size = 20

bbox = ax_right.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_right_upper = inset_axes(
    ax_right, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)

bbox = ax_bottom.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_bottom_upper = inset_axes(
    ax_bottom, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)
```

However, the inset will be squished; even though I'm specifying a square aspect ratio (with respect to the host axis), they end up compressed:

[image]

I can force the aspect ratio of the tiny axes to be equal:

```
inset_right_upper.set_aspect('equal')
inset_bottom_upper.set_aspect('equal')
```

But that makes them smaller and moves them (towards the center, here).

[image]

It seems inset axes behave differently when they are insets to axes_divider axes, and some patterns how one could set up insets with a specific aspect ratio, size and position for normal axes don't work anymore. Is there a programmatic solution for creating e.g. square inset axes for non-square `axes_divider.append_axes` axes – while keeping the desired (edge-hugging) position and size, just as it works for normal axes (see the second example)?

Comment: The question nicely visualizes what can be done. But the actual problem is a bit too short. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could that also be visualized or at least explained from the given figures?

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the figure is not drawn, the divider axes do not yet know their size. Therefore their bbox is just as large as the parent bbox. The inset_axes are therefore calculated in terms of the main axes size.

This is actually a more or less general rule: If you want to use `.get_window_extent()` on an artist, you need to make sure it has been drawn at least once prior to getting its extent.

To draw the figure,

```
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

base_ax = plt.subplot(111)

divider = make_axes_locatable(base_ax)
ax_right = divider.append_axes("right", size="20%", pad="1%")
ax_bottom = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="20%", pad="1%")

loc="upper left"
size = 20

plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
bbox = ax_right.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_right_upper = inset_axes(
    ax_right, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)


bbox = ax_bottom.get_window_extent()
ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
inset_bottom_upper = inset_axes(
    ax_bottom, width=str(size / ratio) + '%', height=str(size) + '%', loc=loc)

plt.show()
```

producing

[image]

Comment: This clearly answers my toy example, so I am accepting. However, it somehow does *not* work for my actual problem ...

Comment: Turns out all it needed was an additional `ax.set_aspect("auto", adjustable="box")` and now it works.

Comment: your code works in the notebook, but not in e.g. the interactive backend. Instead, I have to call plt.show to get the same result; drawing the canvas is not sufficient. However, I can't plt.show at that part of my code. Is there a way of dealing with that?

Comment: The code here runs as it is as a script. What is "the interactive backend" in your case? How do you run the code?

Comment: When I run it outside of the notebook (i.e., running it as a script), I get: https://i.imgur.com/TowWLEE.png
 ('MacOSX' backend)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the MacOS backend. But it seems that is the crux here. Do you need to use it? Would it work if you use "TkAgg" or "Qt5Agg" as backend?

Comment: Sadly we have to support a wide array of backends, with MacOSX being fairly common.